# does xml ignores (,) OR (-)??? (xml of flash object)

Tags: xml, flash

```
<SCENE>
<xml_image>telcos.jpg</xml_image>
<xml_bigtext>TELCOS</xml_bigtext>
<xml_smalltext>New-Age Properties, Wifi Everywhere</xml_smalltext>
<xml_align>right</xml_align>
<xml_bigtextcolor>#ffffff</xml_bigtextcolor>
<xml_bigtextshadow>#0000000</xml_bigtextshadow>
<xml_bigtextcolor>#ffffff</xml_bigtextcolor>
<xml_bigtextshadow>#0000000</xml_bigtextshadow>
```

this is the `xml` file of my `flash`.But ignores the hyphen(-) and comma(,) like
`New-Age` comes like `NewAge` and
`Properties,` comes like `PropertiesWifi`  **WHY?**

Answer (score 2):

`,` and `-` are perfectly fine in XML. I guess whatever is *parsing* your XML is ignoring these characters. Maybe you need to escape them in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your XML node values in `<![CDATA[]]>`, it`s good practice anyway!

(On a completely different note, highfun is the most hilarious spelling of hyphen I`ve seen :) )